# forEach() and reduce() not working with arguments

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I have two arrays (a,b) and my task is to find the difference of their volumes i.e. i have to multiply all elements of array a, then do the same for array b and then subtract the two to find the difference.

I tried using `forEach()` and `reduce()` in conjuction with `arguments` but it seems that the last element of each array is left out and what I get as output is `NaN`.

This is my code

```
  function findDifference(a, b) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var results = [];
  args.forEach(function(argument){
    return argument.reduce(function(a,b){
     results.push(a*b);
    });
  });
  return results;
}
```

and this is my output for `findDifference([3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 4]);`

```
[6, NaN, 4, NaN]
```

Looks like the multiplication stops with the second element of each array. Any ideas?

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, `forEach` does not respect some return value, what do you want with that?

Comment: so the results array should be [30, 16] i.e. the multiplication of all elements within each array. And from there finding the difference is easy, i just have to subtract the two.

Comment: You have only two arrays, why all these complications with `arguments`? Just `return product(a) - product(b)` where `product` is `ary.reduce(x, y => x * y)`

Comment: @georg  You could pass more than 2 arrays to this function, the `a, b` parameters are misleading here.

Comment: @Keith: the question states `I have two arrays...` Passing more than two wouldn't make any sense - what exactly is the difference of three numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just multiply the given arrays and take the delta of the results?

```js
function findDifference(a, b) {
    return [a, b]
        .map(a => a.reduce((a, b) => a * b))
        .reduce((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log(findDifference([3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 4]));
```

With arguments.

```js
function findDifference(a, b) {
    return Array.prototype
        .map.call(arguments, a => a.reduce((a, b) => a * b))
        .reduce((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log(findDifference([3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing each multiplication in result array, you can store the result of all the multiplication of each array in `result` array.

```js
function findDifference(a, b) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var results = [];
  args.forEach(function(argument){
    results.push(argument.reduce(function(a,b){
      return a*b;
    }));
  });
  
  return results;
}
console.log(findDifference([3, 2, 5], [1, 4, 4]));
```